# Bidirectional api testing using Karate

Tags: api, testing, karate, bidirectional

I have a client (cwmp) and a server (acs). I want to test the server. Client and server communicate with each other using a bidirectional protocol. Messages are SOAP over HTTP.

[image: sequence diagram]

Is there a way to test the server using Karate or other framework? I can figure out how to send messages, but not how to receive them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "magic". You have to do some work to handle the calls coming from "ACS".

Use the pattern in this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

Ask a new *specific* question if needed.

Comment: Thomas, I have other little question, is it possible to do something like wiremock verify with karate mocks? In wiremock there is a journal that record requests. It can be reseted before each test and verified when test finishes (in my example is necessary for checking if the last empty http post was sent)

Comment: @italktothewind yes, in a more generic way. karate mocks are http servers that hold "state" in memory, read docs, see video: https://youtu.be/yu3uupBZyxc?t=2387 add another end-point which your test can call to see what calls were made